# Port libgdx application to iOS

Tags: ios, libgdx

I made my game using libgdx which is a cross-platform framework which supports desktop, Android and html5 (using Google Web Toolkit). What could be a possible route to port my game to iOS?

Answer (score 5):

Now you can port your game to iOS. The steps to do this (as described [here](http://www.badlogicgames.com/wordpress/?p=3107)) are:

1. Make sure you have all prerequisits for libgdx development for iOS, except Xamarin.iOS/Monotouch!
2. Open Eclipse, and install the RoboVM plugin from [here](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/robovm/eclipse/). This will install everything you need.
3. Get the libgdx source and import all projects into Eclipse.
4. Right click any of the xxx-robovm projects in Eclipse, select Run As, then iOS Device App, or iOS Simulator App.
5. See things running on your iOS simulator or device! (Note that you need to provision your device to be able to run anything on it, which costs you 90$/year. Thanks Apple!)

But there are some issues. Read all the information [here](http://www.badlogicgames.com/wordpress/?p=3107).

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you could [port to GWT](http://www.badlogicgames.com/wordpress/?p=2308) and then use something like [GWT on PhoneGap](http://code.google.com/p/gwt-phonegap/) to get the app into iOS.  (Hmm... I'm not sure if the GWT on PhoneGap link above is for running GWT on PhoneGap, or for porting PhoneGap apps to GWT?)

I have no experience with either of these steps, so I can't say what wouldn't work.  But like a game of "telephone" I suspect each step will degrade the experience slightly, so the result may not be worthwhile.

Answer (score 0):

The creator of libGDX, **Mario Zechner**, himself says in the following blog post that libGDX games require a MonoTouch license for running games written in libGDX to run on iOS! See [First libGDX game on iOS](http://www.badlogicgames.com/wordpress/?p=2688) and here are some, [Screenshots of libGDX iOS Demos](http://www.java-gaming.org/index.php?topic=27495.0). Hope this helps :)