# Can I use Libgdx to create a game that runs on multiple platforms?

Tags: libgdx, android, ios, linux

I created my first game using Libgdx and Android Studio. The game runs smoothly on my Android phone. How can I run it on an Apple phone with IOS or a computer with Linux etc.?

Comment: "Can libGDX be used on multiple devices" seems to be answered by [the very first paragraph on libGDX.com](https://libgdx.com/): "libGDX is a cross-platform Java game development framework based on OpenGL (ES) that **works on Windows, Linux, macOS, Android, your browser and iOS**." So, as currently phrased, this question does not demonstrate research effort. Consider typing "how to port libGDX Android Studio app to iOS" or similar into your favourite search engine to find existing guides and tutorials. Post here when you encounter a specific issue not adequately answered by your research.

Comment: You may also be interested in past Q&A on related topics, including [libGDX deployment questions](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/105773/39518) and [Port libGDX application to iOS](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/29872/39518). The search box and Related Links sidebar will help you find more.

Comment: Thanks for the info

Answer (score 0):

The way to deploy your game on all possible platforms is described [here on official LibGdx wiki](https://libgdx.com/wiki/deployment/deploying-your-application). Mostly it is just running single command:

- Desktop (JRE binary - Windows, Linux, MAC OS X): `./gradlew desktop:dist`
- HTML: `./gradlew html:dist`
- iOS: `./gradlew ios:createIPA`

Desktop and HTML should work out of box without any configuration, but you can sometime hit small issues with HTML build. I have no experience with iOS, but you need to set signing certificates. Check link above for more details.